# some error in output in using macro in C

Tags: c

my code is:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define sq(x) x*x*x

  void main()
  {
    printf("Cube is : %d.",sq(6+5));
    getch();
  }
```

The output is:-

```
Cube is : 71.
```

now please help me out that why the output is 71 and not 1331...

thank you in advance.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why macros are considered evil in C++. That's actually being translated to `6+5*6+5*6+5`, or `6+(5*6)+(5*6)+5`. What else is evil is your `main` signature: http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: hmmm... you are right. thats a quite evil approach.

Comment: Well, in C there's not too much you can do about it. By putting it into a function, you can only have one `sq` function taking one type of argument. In C++, you can overload that to keep the same name, but provide versions for whatever argument types you want. You can even use a template to "overload" it for every type. Those better alternatives are why this macro shouldn't be used there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need parentheses around the argument.

```
#define sq(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))
```

Without the parentheses, the expression will expand to:

```
6+5*6+5*6+5
```

Which you can see why it would evaluate to `71`.

A safer solution would be to use an inline function instead. But, you would need to define a different one for each type. It might also be more clear to rename the macro.

```
static inline int cube_int (int x) { return x*x*x; }
```

Comment: but still how the output is 71. can u explain me that with a reason.

Comment: You should change it to a function otherwise `int x = 7; sq(x++)` won't do what you think

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: `6+5*6+5*6+5` = `6+(5*6)+(5*6)+5` = `6+30+30+5` = `71`

Answer (score 8):

Always shield your macro arguments with parenthesis:

```
#define sq(x) ((x) * (x) * (x))
```

Consider the evaluation without the parenthesis:

```
6 + 5 * 6 + 5 * 6 + 5
```

And recall that `*` has a higher precedence than `+`, so this is:

```
6 + 30 + 30 + 5 = 71;
```

Get to know the precedence rules if you don't already: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 3):

If you define the macro like this:

```
#define sq(x) x*x*x
```

And call it:

```
sq(6+5);
```

The pre-processor will generate this code:

```
6+5*6+5*6+5
```

Which is, due to operator precedence, equivalent to:

```
6+(5*6)+(5*6)+5
```

That's why, the macro arguments must be parenthesized:

```
#define sq(x) (x)*(x)*(x)
```

So that pre-processor output becomes:

```
(6+5)*(6+5)*(6+5)
```

However, if you pass some arguments with side-effects such as (i++):

```
sq(i++)
```

It will be expanded to:

```
(i++)*(i++)*(i++)
```

So, be careful, perhaps you need a function

Comment: And just in case the OP doesn't realize, `(i++)*(i++)*(i++)` is undefined behaviour.